# Layer navigation shows not matching attributes with custom products collection

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation, product-collection

I have to try to implement alphabetical order for custom product collection in default category products listing page.

Our custom products collection is working fine but left side layer navigation is not displayed matching attribute with option values based on custom products collection. kindly refer the attachment image.

How to deal with this side layer navigation? Kindly advice me.

[image]

Comment: Magento version?

Comment: you need to customized the layer navigation collection same as main colletions.

Comment: @Gopal - Magento version is 2.1.x

Comment: @DhirenVasoya . Yes I tried too. added a same filter in to the getProductCollection method in layer.php model file.. Thanks

Comment: Did you get correct result?

Comment: Yes get the result but not matching with products collection like above image. Thanks.@DhirenVasoya